# Ruby: I want child class to always declare certain class variables

Tags: ruby, inheritance, abstract-class

`A` is a parent class and `B` and `C` are it's subclasses. I can ensure that `B` and `C` both have method `hello` by adding following lines in class `A`.

```
def hello
  raise "Implement hello method in sub class"
end
```

How can I acheive the same for a class variable that each subclass of `A` should have?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question (without knowing what you call a `variable`), you can simply define variable like this:

```
def my_variable
  @my_variable || raise 'Not defined'
end
```

… rather than :

```
 attr_accessor :my_variable # a 'true' instance variable
```

Hope it helps.